# Why does the invocation of the defined constructor causes an error in the declaration of the structure, and how can I fix it?

Tags: c++

Consider the following short program, which compiles.

```
void foobar() {
}

template <typename F> struct Foo{
    F workFunction;
    Foo(F f) :  workFunction(f) { }
};

int main(){
    Foo<decltype(foobar)> foo1();
}
```

If I change the line in `main` to the following,

```
Foo<decltype(foobar)> foo1(foobar);
```

The code fails to compile with the following error.

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2    Task.cc   -o Task
Task.cc: In instantiation of ‘struct Foo<void()>’:
Task.cc:10:38:   required from here
Task.cc:5:7: error: field ‘Foo<void()>::workFunction’ invalidly declared function type
     F workFunction;
```

Why does this happen, and how can I correctly pass the function?

Here is the output of `g++ -v`.

```
$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Debian 4.9.2-10' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,c++,java,go,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++ --prefix=/usr --program-suffix=-4.9 --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id --libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.9 --libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --disable-browser-plugin --enable-java-awt=gtk --enable-gtk-cairo --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64/jre --enable-java-home --with-jvm-root-dir=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-jvm-jar-dir=/usr/lib/jvm-exports/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.9-amd64 --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --enable-objc-gc --enable-multiarch --with-arch-32=i586 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.9.2 (Debian 4.9.2-10)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "works"?

Comment: @juanchopanza, I mean that I'm trying to pass the function into the constructor so it can be invoked later.

Comment: And what do you mean by "works"?

Comment: @juanchopanza, I believe the word "works" has been deleted from my question, so I'm not sure in what context you're asking about that.

Comment: Sigh. OK, what do you mean by "work" then.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Sorry I need to correct the title of the question.

Comment: @juanchopanza, Essentially, I am trying to capture the function with a templated type.

Answer (score 2):

```
Foo<decltype(foobar)> foo1();
```

is not an object instantiation, it is a declaration of a function that accepts no arguments and returns `Foo<decltype(foobar)>`.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the answer from @bipll, the first statement you ask about:

```
Foo<decltype(foobar)> foo1();
```

is simply a declaration of a function returning a `Foo`, not an initialization.

As to the second question, how can we make the following work?

```
Foo<decltype(foobar)> foo1(foobar);
```

We could simply change the template to [**decay the captured type**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay):

```
template <typename F> struct Foo{
    typename std::decay<F>::type workFunction;
    Foo(F f) :  workFunction(f) { }
};
```

Now, using an example:

```
#include <type_traits>

int foobar() {
    return 1;
}

template <typename F> struct Foo{
    typename std::decay<F>::type workFunction;
    Foo(F f) :  workFunction(f) { }
};

int main(){
    Foo<decltype(foobar)> foo1(foobar);
    std::cout << foo1.workFunction();
}
```

will return the expected output of `1`.